# Error creating bean with name 'resolver' defined in WebMVCConfig resource [/com.chat.config/]

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, javabeans

I had problems with context initialization. I don't use xml-configuration files. I read many articles about similar problems but.. I've wanted to make spring configuration with no xml, but error appears. Please help to solve.

```
`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resolver' defined in com.chat.config.WebMVCConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver]: Factory method 'resolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
```

Here is my WebMVCConfig

```
  @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.chat")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/views/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();

    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver().setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver().setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

WebInit

```
    public class WebInit extends 
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    // Этот метод должен содержать конфигурации которые инициализируют Beans
    // для инициализации бинов у нас использовалась аннотация @Bean
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebMVCConfig.class
        };
    }

    // Тут добавляем конфигурацию, в которой инициализируем ViewResolver
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebMVCConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/","/login", "/chat","/dialog","/registration" };
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyChat</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyChat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    resolver().setPrefix("/views/");
    resolver().setSuffix(".jsp");
```

Your method name is `resolver` and you're calling `resolver()` repeatedly. This is an infinite recursive call. It should be this instead:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
```

Comment: =DDDDDD,   ahahaha, thx, man))))  That;s really fun)))) i was solving it 2-3 hours.. and it was so stupid)  Thank u so much!

Comment: Tell me one more thing, please! Default page will be "index.jsp" how can i change it? 
Am i right that now spring looks for pages by path: /webapp/views?
or /webapp/?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Not sure about default page. I think you can just set a request mapping to `"/"` which will work as a default. You don't need to manually specify each mapping, either. You can just use `/**` unless you want to use a whitelist, but that's a lot of maintenance when adding pages.